# How to I run OMXPlayer in windowed mode from Python?

Tags: omxplayer, python-3

When I run this program in Python 3 it is working but the video is in full-screen.

```
from subprocess import run
videoPath = "/home/pi/video_3.h264"
omx = run(["omxplayer",videoPath])
```

As soon as I add arguments to run the video in windowed nothing happens:

```
from subprocess import run
videoPath = "/home/pi/video_3.h264"
omx = run(["omxplayer","--win 1,1,500,400",videoPath])
```

I tried `omxplayer --win 1,1,500,400 /home/pi/video_3.h264`in terminal and it is working. Is my Python syntax wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you try with only one hyphon?

Answer (score 3):

Arguments given to Python's subprocess and friends are generally not allowed to have spaces.

```
omx = run(["omxplayer", '--win', '1,1,500,400', videoPath])
```

The above should work. In this instance, single or double quotes don't matter. Make sure to have '--win' and the geometry specification next to each other in the correct order.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
omx = run(["omxplayer", --win '1,1,500,400',videoPath])
```

Comment: It's best if the answer contains some explanation as to why it's the correct answer. This not only helps the one who asked, but also others in the future. For instance, why do the single-quotes matter? That seems to be the only change between what the OP had an error with and what you have.

Comment: Are you sure you typed this correctly, cctv? `--win` in the Python code would just give a syntax error as it's not wrapped in a string of any sort. Did you perhaps mean to wrap the whole thing in double quotes, then have the single quotes as well?